# Grid.Mvc.Ajax extension grid initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm very new to Web GUI dev using JQuery & Ajax and I'm trying to get the nuget package Grid.MVC.Ajax working. The readme states the following:

```
Follow thse steps to use Grid.Mvc.Ajax

1. Include ~/Scripts/gridmvc-ext.js after your ~/Scripts/grimvc.js include.

2. Include ~/Content/ladda-bootstrap/ladda-themeless.min.css CSS after your Bootstrap CSS/LESS include.

3. Include Ladda-bootstrap Javascript via the ~/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/ladda.min.js
 and ~/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/spin.min.js.

4. Create a view model for you grid data, for example:
public Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

5. Add a Razor partial view for your grid data that uses an AjaxGrid<T> as the model type, 
Where T is your view model type:

@using GridMvc.Html
@using GridMvc.Sorting
@model Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGrid<Models.Person>

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Add(c => c.FirstName);
      columns.Add(c => c.LastName);
    }).Sortable(true).WithPaging(10)

6. Add a controller action to retrieve the data for the first page of data that includes the Ajax pager HTML:

 public JsonResult Persons()
        {
            var vm = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" }
            }
            .AsQueryable();
            var ajaxGridFactory = new Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGridFactory();
            var grid = ajaxGridFactory.CreateAjaxGrid(vm, 1, false);
        }

7. Add a controller action to retrieve data for paged items that returns a JsonResult without the Ajax page HTML:

 public JsonResult PersonsPaged(int page)
        {
            var vm = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" }
            }
            .AsQueryable();
            var ajaxGridFactory = new Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGridFactory();
            var grid = ajaxGridFactory.CreateAjaxGrid(vm, page, true);
        }

8. Call the ajaxify Grid.Mvc.Ajax JavaScript plug-in method setting the non-paged and paged controller actions and optionally a form
to apply additional filtering to the grid. All input and select elements in the given form will be passed into your paged and non-paged controller actions:

 $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().ajaxify({
                getPagedData: '/Home/Persons',
                getData : '/Home/PersonsPaged',
                gridFilterForm: $("#gridFilters")
            });
```

I have set things up as stated but I'm having problems in step 8. as I'm not sure how to call the JavaScript code in order to populate the grid. I have enclosed the above in a $(document).ready call but that doesn't seem to work :-( Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make sure the grid in your HTML has the .grid-mvc class. Otherwise it would find the element to intialise. e.g. <div class="grid-mvc"></div>

Comment: for me when i do that the compiler is failing because there is no return from the method.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options: `loadPage` and `refreshFullPage`

this will call your PersonsPaged method:

```
$(".grid-mvc")
   .gridmvc()
   .loadPage()
```

and this will call your Persons method.

```
$(".grid-mvc")
   .gridmvc()
   .refreshFullGrid()
```

also, in your Persons and PersonsPaged you can return a JSON like this:

```
public ActionResult Persons()
{
    var vm = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var ajaxGridFactory = new AjaxGridFactory();
    var grid = ajaxGridFactory.CreateAjaxGrid(vm, 1, false);

    return Json(new { Html = grid.ToJson("_YourPartialWithGridCode", this), grid.HasItems },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to work with this. I don't have an idea. Can anyone help me with this pls..? Is there any tutorial or documentation to understand better.

Comment: @JeevaJsb Take a look at http://gridmvcajax.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Grid.Mvc.Demo/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem adding the URI.js file on the scripts tag before gridmvc.js and gridmvc-ext.js. When I installed Grid.Mvc.Ajax by Nuget, it added this file.

I called the code inside the $(document).ready(function() { ... }) and used twice ways.
1 - The javascript object of the grid using the grid's name.
2 - I did the same way that you did calling ajaxify method after gridmvc method using a jquery selector and it worked to me.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().ajaxify(
            {
                getPagedData: "/Product/Grid",
                getData: "/Product/Index"
            });
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        pageGrids.productGrid.ajaxify(
        {
            getPagedData: "/Product/Grid",
            getData: "/Product/Index"
        });
    });
</script>
```

"productGrid" is the grid's name. I hope to have helped.