# displaying data on view like Grid; in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view

i am newbie to MVC 3 and Linq to Sql, trying to display data on VIEW which i am getting from database. I did it via tables but don't like it, i need something like Gridview (add, delete, update) etc but couldn't find proper way. i tried Grid.MVC but couldn't find a way to connect it to my code. Any way for grid display with respect to my code ?

Controller:

```
using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models;
namespace EmployeeAttendance_app.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Precise Technology Consultants";
            var DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();
            var EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAttendance_Sp();
            return View(EmployeeAtd);
        }
```

View:

```
<table>

 <tr>

      <th>
       Employer ID
      </th>
      <th>
       Employer Name
      </th>
      <th>
       Rec Date
      </th>
      <th>
       Rec Time
      </th>
      <th>
       Department Name
      </th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (GetAttendance_SpResult emp in (IEnumerable<GetAttendance_SpResult>)ViewData.Model) 
 {


     <tr>

      <td>@emp.EmplID</td>
      <td>@emp.EmplName</td>
      <td>@emp.RecDate</td>
      <td>@emp.RecTime</td>
      <td>@emp.DeptName</td>

     </tr>

 }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tried Grid yet (have been using tables and for loops);but, a quick search turned up Grid.MVC.ajax
  [Grid.Mvc.Ajax extension grid initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609625/grid-mvc-ajax-extension-grid-initialization)

If (ok when) I try this on Monday,  I'll follow the 8 steps provided in the Grid.MVC.Ajax  readmelink referenced above... and update this comment...

Answer (score 0):

Two methods I have used are detailed below.

The first was a hybrid of jquery, datatables and mvc.

There is a good article on this at code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a

The second was with kendo ui mvc helper grid:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/overview

The second being a pay for component.